# Sinon stub throwing Attempted to wrap object which is already wrapped

Tags: node.js, express, sinon

Although there are posts regarding this , I could not fix it using before, after functions and restoring the objects. Posting the code below:-

```
var Log = sinon.stub(hello, 'someEvent', function(type, name){
        var obj = {};
        obj.addData = function(data){
            return;
        };
        obj.complete = function(){
            return;
        }
        return obj;
     }),
    someVar = sinon.stub(servicecore, 'some'),
```

The error I get is:-

```
Attempted to wrap someEvent which is already wrapped.
```

And

```
Attempted to wrap some which is already wrapped.
```

Can someone help with this?

> Edited below

I even tried with before and after functions as suggested:-

```
var Log,someVar;

before(function(){

   Log = sinon.stub(hello, 'someEvent', function(type, name){
            var obj = {};
            obj.addData = function(data){
                return;
            };
            obj.complete = function(){
                return;
            }
            return obj;
         });
    someVar = sinon.stub(servicecore, 'some');

});

after(function(){

    Log.restore();
    someVar.restore();
});
```

Tried even with beforeEach and afterEach functions but same error.

Comment: Is that really a [mcve]? Where else are you calling `sinon.stub`?

Comment: You need to provide the full example. Also remember that if in a previous test you have a stub or a spy, you need to do a **restore**, to avoid conflicts with the subsequents tests.

Comment: Hi @Hosar , sorry I am a noob at this. Where exactly do I need to do the restore.

Answer (score 4):

From the [sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/):

> var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method"); Replaces object.method with a
>   stub function. The original function can be restored by calling
>   object.method.restore(); (or stub.restore();). An exception is thrown
>   if the property is not already a function, to help avoid typos when
>   stubbing methods.

The stub is normally restored after the test is complete using the after or afterEach hooks.

```
  after(function() {
    // runs before all tests in this block
    someVar.restore();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    // runs before each test in this block
    someVar.restore();
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't you stub in the before/beforeEach and restore in the after/afterEach? That's the way I've always done it.

Comment: @cartant My bad, you are right of course. Not enough coffee today.

Answer (score 2):

you are stubbing someVar.some not someVar itself
so you need to restore its method:

```
    someVar.some.restore();
```

If you still have problems, then try to stub using the following method.

```
    someVar.some = sinon.stub();
```

Looks like the same but it is not :) (discovered after hours of swearing)

Anyway let's try the sandbox in sinon to stub from it and just restore the sandbox at the end

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/sandbox/